# Spring tags and facelets

Tags: spring, facelets

Can I use Spring tags with facelets? I have one JSP page, and there is a directive:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
```

Then I can insert the tag `<s:theme code='css' />` (I'm using theme resolver.) Now I need to use theme resolver in another project using facelets instead JSP. There is a namespace declaration instead the JSP directive, isn't?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:em="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/emcomp"
    xmlns:st="http://www.springframework.org/tags">
```

But in Eclipse the namespace is labeled with the warning marker and on server it does not work, because the tag library is missing, althought I have put the library Spring Web MVC in the `lib` directory of Eclipse Internal Glassfish server. The JAR really contains `META-INF/spring.tld`.

I'm unable to find, what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately you cannot. Spring tags are based on a JSP taglib. Facelet taglibs are different from JSP taglibs. The reason you can use the old-fashioned jsp core tags (c:forEach etc) in facelets is because they have been ported to facelet taglibs. AFAIK, there has not been any port done yet of the Spring JSP taglib to a facelet taglib.